# How can I finish a plumbing cleanout in my basement floor?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I am looking for some advice on what do with the main line cleanout in my basement. Currently, we have a hole in basement floor where the mainline and cleanout run. We plan on cleaning out the main line and then put down carpet to cover some tiles. However looking for ideas on what to do with the clean out pipe and hole.

Comment: The usual fix is a stainless steel cleanout cover plate, which is screwed directly into the cleanout plug. Is there some reason this won't work for you? A photo would help.

Comment: Watch out you’re borderline asking for decorating advice which is specifically off topic.  Keep in mind you may need to use that clean out in the future.  Also it’s hard to offer advice when we don’t know the relative location and what you’re trying to accomplish with the area.  Typically clean-outs aren’t out in the middle.  Usually found against a wall where many creative things can be done to hide/camouflage... but that’s decorative advice.